# How to determine the column with multiple items of data has one specified value in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my table:

[image]

I want to change the `TargetCondition` column to 'TRUE' when the `ICD9CODE` column contains a particular range (like between 250 and 250.93).

Please help me do it. Thanks

This is the code here:

```
update demo.fea_02 set TargetCondition = TRUE where ICD9Code like between '%250%' and '%250.93%'
```

got the error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected keyword BETWEEN at [6:17]

Comment: Could I know if there is an ID or composite unique key for each row in this table?

Comment: yes, every line has unique PatientGuid

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You would use `update`:

```
update mytable
    set targetcondition = 'TRUE'
    where icd9code like '%value%';
```

Comment: thanks for your help!  I use the code above but got one error, I edit the code and the error in my question. can you please have a look?

Comment: @RA.IBOY . . . `when` was a typo.

Comment: it works well! thanks for your help, but one more question is that i prefer the selected condition is between a specified range rather a specified value. can you please help me improve it ?

Comment: @RA.IBOY . . . Ask a *new* question.  Provide clear sample data and desired results and an explanation.  Do not put an unreadable image in the question; text table are preferred.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! it really helps me!